# udp packet fragmentation for raw sockets

Tags: c++, sockets, udp, fragmentation

Follow-up of question [packet fragmentation for raw sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187850/packet-fragmentation-for-raw-sockets)

If I have a raw socket implemented as such:

```
  if ((sip_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW)) < 0)
      {
    cout << "Unable to create the SIP sockets."<< sip_socket<<" \n";
    return -3;
      }

   if ( setsockopt(sip_socket, IPPROTO_IP, IP_HDRINCL, &one, sizeof(one)) == -1)
      {
   cerr << "Unable to set option to Raw Socket.\n";
   return -4;
      };
```

how can I set the **ipHdr->fragment_offset** (16 bits including 3 bit flags) if I have a packet of size 1756 (not including the IP header)?
Do I need to prepare two packets-one of size 1480 and another of size 276, and then slap IP headers on both packets?

Can anyone point to an example code for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to prepare two packets, each with their own IP header.

If you put 1480 bytes of data in the first packet and 276 in the second, then the IP headers should be identical, except for these fields:

- `Fragment Offset`: set to `0` in the first packet, and `1480` in the second;
- `Total Length`: set to 1480 plus the header length in the first packet, and 276 plus the header length in the second packet;
- `MF` flag: set to `1` in the first packet and `0` in the second;
- `Header Checksum`: Recalculated over the different headers as appropriate.

Comment: Yes I got it done. Just one more thing. identifier has to be same for both the fragments. Thanks.

Comment: Of course - *all* the fields other than the 4 I listed should be identical between the fragments.

Comment: Absolutely. I meant to say that the identifier must be identical and non-zero.

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: the fragment offset value is expressed as 8byte blocks. So for the above
the first packet, fragment offset value will be zero but more fragments bit will be set `ipHdr->fragment_offset = 0x01 << 13`

For the second packet, fragment offset value is 1480/8 = 135 (same as right shift by 3bits) and flags is zero
`ipHdr->fragment_offset = 1480 >> 3`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).